# Is this non-disassemblable LEGO instruction step real?

Tags: set-identification, instructions, disassembly

I've seen this image shared a few times around the internet as an example of a LEGO instruction step that assembles pieces in such a way that they cannot be disassembled (at-least not without some serious strain on the parts).

[image]

If one were to insert that Technic axle into that hole, it would sit flush inside holding the other red piece in place, and since the black piece wraps around the back, it would not be possible to slide it off the axle without some substantial bending.

Trying to find the source of the image has proven difficult, and those who share it don't ever seem to include the source of the image.

Is this from a real LEGO set's instruction, or is it faked?

Comment: Last time I remember looking at one of those axle-joiners, there was a hole of a small diameter that a toothpick might be able to poke the axle out through. Is that the case?

Comment: @Eric In the red piece yes, but it would be covered over by the solid black piece. You would have to bend it some to do that (which is probably the best way to try to remove it).

Comment: Oh wow, I missed that the left end is solid, and assumed it was an axle hole.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out it is real, just not from a single set itself, but from the official instructions for a combo-model between Exo-Force models [7700-1: Stealth Hunter](https://brickset.com/sets/7700-1/Stealth-Hunter) and 
[7701-1: Grand Titan](https://brickset.com/sets/7701-1/Grand-Titan) to make [Mountain Warrior](http://exo-force.wikia.com/wiki/Mountain_Warrior).

[image]

You can find the pictured step on page 26 of the [instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20151105064625/http://cache.lego.com/Media/Download/ExoforceBuildingInstructions/otherfiles/downloadEB95FFB32F560F061D7B883F43AC4D04/7701_CombiPDF.pdf).

[image]